# ArcGIS Pro Layer to KML With Multiple Images Per Feature Only Displays One Image in Google Earth

Tags: kml, arcgis-pro, google-earth, attachments, layer-to-kml

Question: Why is it that when I use Layer to KML in ArcGIS Pro 2.4.1 I can only view one image per feature on Google Earth Pro? All the attachments are listed inside the popup on GE, but the links for the additional images do nothing.

These data are from Collector with a 1:Many cardinality for the photo attachments. So far I have tried everything I can think of in the Configure Popups window for the layer. The "Show First Image Only" box is NOT checked. I went through all the menus in GE too, but I don't see anything relevant. I have read through ESRI help for the Layer to KML tool and Configure Popups. I have been Googling for a couple hours and found other people have had this problem, but no solution is given.

Comment: Hard to tell what's going on without knowledge of your data or code. Can you expand a bit on what you mean by "image per feature"?  Would help if you can share your KML or a sample.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't share the data or KML as its sensitive data for work. What I mean by "image per feature" is that you see one point  feature on the KML. It has  multiple images associated with it. When you click on that point in the KML a popup appears. That popup displays only the first photo, and beneath that photo are links to the others. Those links do not work.

Comment: As a test, can you try running this version of the tool and seeing if it works:  https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=5d8704c938ea4715b59eebabcd96c1d9

Comment: Tested tool from KHibma. Shows no image in GE popup just the links. When link is clicked it closes the popup, zooms out to the max extent, and no picture is displayed.